# Check the next line

Tags: c, file, io

I have file containing multiple customer records formatted like:

```
CUSTOMER ...
details...
details...
CUSTOMER...
details...
details...
details...
CUSTOMER...
.
.
```

I need to split the file into two. Currently, I count all the lines in the file and divide by `2`, and then check if that line starts with the string `CUSTOMER` or not.

If it does, how can I print all the lines before CUSTOMER?

and

If it does not, how can I check if the next line starts with `CUSTOMER`?

My Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ioarea[1000];
    int TotCustLines=0,i=0;

    int reqLine=0;
    int getLine=0;

    if((inFile=fopen(argv[inFileName],"r"))==NULL)
        printf("Failed to open input file");

    while(fgets(ioarea,BUFFER_SIZE,inFile))
    {
       TotCustLines++;  
    }
}
if(TotCustLines/2==0)
    reqLine=(TotCustLines/2);
else
    reqLine=(TotCustLines/2)+1;
fseek(inFile,1,SEEK_SET);
while(fgets(ioarea,BUFFER_SIZE,inFile))
{
    getLine++;
    if(getLine==reqLine)
    {
        if(strncmp(getLine,"CUSTOMER RECORD",15)==0)
        //How to write all the lines before customer record.
        //If not how can i check next line.
    }
}
```

Please suggest a solution. I am new to the C file concept.

Comment: `if(strncmp(getLine,"CUSTOMER RECORD",15)==0)` --> `if(strcmp(ioarea,"CUSTOMER RECORD\n")==0)`

Comment: Do you want to create 2 new files, and remove the original file?

Comment: @anatolyg I want to create two files,but do not want to remove the original file.

Comment: have you tried anything from either answer?  both address several of your questions.

Comment: @ ryyker yes i am trying with your suggestions. thanks for your help

Comment: Comment any questions you have under the answer so I will be flagged to come back and answer if I can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach you can use to read a file, then search through resulting lines for CUSTOMER (or anything else):

1) get file size  (use `fseek()/ftell()` ) , or use *example 1* to get line count, and longest line.
2) create and allocate memory for an array of strings, `char **buffer;`  see *example 2*
3) read file into array using `fgets()`, indexing through `buffer[index]` as you go.
4) Array buffer[] now contains count of *index* lines in file.

You can now use the `strstr()` string comparison function to look for CUSTOMER in the lines you have stored.

***Example 1*** Way to get count of lines in file, and length longest line (for creating memory)

```
int cnt=0;
int len=0;
int keep=0;
char line[260];// == MAX_PATH_LEN in windows, pick longer value if needed.
while(fgets(line, 260, fp))//get each line in file
{            
    len = strlen(line);//track length of each new line
    if(len > keep)  keep = len;//keep only longest line
    cnt++;                      
}  //keep will have value for longest line, cnt will have number of lines
```

***Example 2***  Creating memory for an array of C strings (`char **string;`) :

***Note:***  example of calling function create and call:

```
char **variable = {0};  
int cnt, maxlen;  
variable = allocMemoryStr(variable, &cnt, &maxlen);
```

........

```
char ** allocMemoryStr(char **strings, int numStrings, int maxLen)
{
    int i;
    strings = calloc(numStrings, sizeof(char*));// create pointers to arrays
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      strings[i] = calloc(maxLen + 1, sizeof(char));// create memory for each array
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use temp file to write modified data.

```
1) Read old file line by line
2) Check (using strncmp()) / modify data 
3) Write modified data to a new temp file
4) After completing all the modification, simply replace temp file with your old file (using rename()).
```

Another better solution is to use a library like 'The Standard Function Library', which will store data in the form:

```
[CUSTOMER_ID]
    Info1 = value1
    Infon = "value n"
```

see http://legacy.imatix.com/html/sfl/index.htm for 'The Standard Function Library'

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to write all lines up to a selected line; at least not directly. Your code must "do the work twice": after it determines the number of customer lines in each of the two output files, it has to start over, read line by line, and output each line into the needed file.

To count the customer records:

```
while(fgets(ioarea,BUFFER_SIZE,inFile))
{
    if(strncmp(getLine,"CUSTOMER RECORD",15)==0)
        TotCustLines++;  
}
```

Then, open two files for writing:

```
FILE *file1;
FILE *file2;
FILE *file_req;
int customer_counter = 0;

...

file1 = fopen("file1.out", "w");
file2 = fopen("file2.out", "w");
file_req = file1; // start outputting to the first file
```

After resetting the input file, do the line-reading and customer-counting loop again, but this time with some added logic:

```
while(fgets(ioarea,BUFFER_SIZE,inFile))
{
    if(strncmp(getLine,"CUSTOMER RECORD",15)==0)
        customer_counter++;
    if (customer_counter == reqLine)
        file_req = file2; // switch to the second file
    fputs(ioarea, file_req); // write the line to whatever file it must go to
}
```

Some notes:

To start reading file from the beginning, use `rewind`. You can also use `fseek` with seek position 0 (note: not 1).

```
rewind(file); // does the same as fseek
```

To divide a number by 2, you don't need to check whether it's divisible by 2:

```
reqLine = (TotCustLines + 1) / 2;
```

You have that macro `BUFFER_SIZE` that roughly determines the length of the longest line you expect. You should use it for your buffer declaration too. If you ever decide to change it, the buffer's size will be adjusted automatically.

```
char ioarea[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

However, using a large constant for that purpose is inherently unsafe (opens your program to unexpected bugs and hacker exploits), but I guess you don't want to think about it at this stage.